# Which compiler did macport use?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction

I'm working on a c++ project which just implemented some of the shared pointer features from boost and/or TR1. Since the upgrade, my code no longer compiles with gcc 4.2.1 (provided by Xcode), I'm installing gcc 4.5.x which is suppose to provide the aforementioned features. I need to recompile mpich2 (and then my code) with the new compiler and I want to be sure macport is using the right one.

```
sudo port install gcc45
gcc_select mp-gcc45
```

should have gotten the job done, but I'd like port to tell me which compiler it is using.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[MacPorts - Using the Right Compiler](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/UsingTheRightCompiler)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It only shows an unpleasant manual hack to figure out which compiler macports is **currently** using. It says nothing at all about figuring out which compiler **historically** got used on any given port. If the user changed anything since, this may well give the wrong answer.